# Allowing an unauthorized POST to an AuthorizeAttribute-decorated Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a "Add to Cart" button that is always visible, but requires authentication to actually add the item to the cart. So right now, the `AddToCart` action has an `AuthorizeAttribute` on it. So when someone clicks the button, a `POST` is made to the action, which redirects to the login screen. And after logging, a GET request is automatically made to the page to which I wanted to `POST`.

Is there a better way of handling this?

I could gray out the "Add to Cart" button with a message that says, "Login to add to cart", but this seems ugly and not very user friendly.

I could change the redirect code to look for a certain URL, and then `POST` to that URL, but this seems hacky.

I could allow a `GET` to the URL, so when it redirects, it works, but `Get`'s shouldn't change data.

Any ideas how I can best handle this scenario?

Comment: You can change the button to point to a different action when the client is not logged in!

Comment: You can override filters on MVC5 but I'd stay with @Fals here and send the post to another url (some TemporaryCharController which can handle that) to avoid messing with security.